# Stack Data Structure as a Template: Main method do not identify methods in stack

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stack

Please have a look at the following code,

**Stack.h**

```
template <typename T>

class Stack
{
public:
    Stack(int number)
    {
        maxSize = number;
        top = -1;
        stackData = new T*[maxSize];
    }

    ~Stack()
    {
        delete [] stackData;
    }

    int count()
    {

    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if(top==-1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool isFull()
    {
        if(top== (maxSize-1))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    *T pop()
    {
        if(!isEmpty())
        {
            return stackData[top--]; // Remove Item From Stack
        }
    }

    *T peek()
    {
        T *peekData =  &stackData[top];
        return peekData;
    }

    void push(T *pushValue)
    {
        if(!isFull())
        {
            stackData[++top] = pushValue;
        }
    }

private:
    int maxSize;
    T ** stackData;
    int top;
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    Stack<double> doubleStack(5);
    double doubleValue = 1.1;

    cout << "pushing elements into the stack" << endl;

    while(i<5)
    {
        doubleStack.push();
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CourseWork2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Main.cpp
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(48): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'pop'
1>          c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(74) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Stack<T>' being compiled
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(48): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(49): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(54): warning C4183: 'pop': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(56): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'peek'
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(56): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(57): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(60): warning C4183: 'peek': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(48): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'pop'
1>          c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\main.cpp(11) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Stack<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=double
1>          ]
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(48): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(49): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(49): warning C4183: 'pop': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(56): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'peek'
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(56): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(57): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\stack.h(57): warning C4183: 'peek': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursework2\coursework2\main.cpp(18): error C2660: 'Stack<T>::push' : function does not take 0 arguments
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=double
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Intellelisense is not identifying any method except isFull(), count() and isEmpty(). I can't code the rest because of this!

Why is this? Please help!

Comment: @PranitPKothari: You are really going for a low reputation :(

Comment: Ya I know, poor me.. it was just casual statement Yohan, really I doesn't mean anything, actually when I gone through your code doesn't seem anything wrong, thats why. Sorry if I hurt you by any way.

Comment: @PranitPKothari: No, it didn't hurt :) But, people might down vote, which is not good :( . There are lot of down voters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put `*` at wrong place in function syntax:

Update:

```
 *T pop()
 *T peek()
```

To:

```
 T* pop()
 T* peek()
```

Comment: 11111 rep. Time to call it a day :p

Comment: can you please tell me what the count() method is supposed to do? we do not change the maxValue, the top is handled in push() and pop(), so why this count() ?????

Comment: I guess `count()` suppose to return `top` which is the element count

Comment: @Yohan, You might want to pass in something to `push` as well. It takes something to push on.

Comment: @chris: yes, i handled it at the first run after the update. thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

You put the asterisk in the wrong spot. It should be:

```
T *pop() {
    //implementation
}
```

and

```
T *peek() {
    //implementation
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reply. I really appreciate it. +1 from me :)